# TensorFlow: how to find the samples that are learned/recalled most poorly?

Tags: tensorflow

With TensorFlow one can collect error information, such as:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(one_hot_y, 1))
```

But it only provides a vector telling which samples are recalled correctly.

However, to really understand what's going on, or what needs to improve, I'd like to find out the most difficult samples to recall. It's like to compute the Euclidean distance between the logits value produced by the neural network and the target one_hot vector for each sample, and select those of the top distances.

Could you share your insight how to do it with TensorFlow?

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/nearest_neighbor.py

Comment: does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`math_ops`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/) documentation!

```
sq_difference = tf.square(tf.add(logits, tf.neg(one_hot_y)))
sq_distances = tf.reduce_sum(sq_difference, axis=1)
```

Note that, `sq_difference` has a dimension `batch_size * output_len` and `sq_distances` has a dimension `output_len`.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But I decide to get out of Tensorflow session as soon as possible, as I find numpy is more comfortable.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. TensorFlow is faster and has most algos implemented

Comment: OK, I will find some time to get myself with minimum fluency in Tensorflow, so that I can explore, and learn. Any good and short tutorial on it? Thanks again.